# CSS span wrap with padding

Tags: css, padding, html, word-wrap

I've got a pretty annoying problem.
I have to make a "table" fwhich containes 3 elements next to each other. The first 2 elements are simple divs, floated left, but the third is a little bit complicated. It must have padding on each sides. By the way, it's a text which can be wrapped by the end of the line.
My problem is that when this element breaks at the end of the first line and the beginning of the second line do not have padding attributes.

I've made a [simple example page](http://jsfiddle.net/8JEzn/) here.

Do you have any solutions for me? I've tried so many different ways...
When the space next to the third element is empty, it's OK, but when I prepend the boxes its completely broken.

Comment: Whats wrong in example-3? Isn't that what you wanted your elements to look like?

Comment: Not exactly. If you set the box-1, box-2 border to 0, the text-box slips next to them without padding-left. But I need a little padding both sides of the text.

Comment: @b_benjamin I'm having a hard time understanding what final result you're looking for.  Are you just trying to create a table without using the table element?  Or do you just want to put padding / gutters around the left/right side of the elements but you're ok with the text wrapping under those elements (you're not trying to create columns). Would it be possible to get a jpeg of what you're looking for?

Comment: @b_benjamin Is this what you looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/8JEzn/7/

Comment: ps. One thing I'm seeing is inline vs box level elements.  Padding is going to work well on the floated DIVs because they're block elements that are floated.  The SPANs are inline and padding won't work as you expect.  CSS display:inline-block and help but you'll have browser support issues.  This page might help. http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Comment: @Fozzyuw: Sorry, my English is not too good (: I attach a screenshot of what I'm trying to reach: http://cl.ly/2C2o15451h3N1r3R3C2m
So the lines which does not wrapped are OK. But there will be lines which will be wrapped before the content of the text lines won't be always as short as the last one.

Comment: @b_benjamin Thanks!  I think I understand.  You want to have padding like this? http://imgur.com/0VgsK

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the width to be dynamic or can it be fixed in size? I would remove the spans, float div.inner and hardcode its width. Something like this:

```
.container {
   overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
   float: left;
   padding: 7px;
   width: 106px; /* you could use percentages to fix the widths if you'd like to keep things dynamic. */
}
```

You could just adjust the padding and avoid setting the border all together. Setting overflow to hidden on the container will force the container element to fit all of the floated elements inside of it. This allows you to avoid inserting a div to clear the floated elements.

You could also express this as a nested list as it's best to avoid unnecessary divs:

```
<ol id="examples_list">
  <li>
    <ul class="container">
      <li class="box">...</li>
      <li class="box">...</li>
      <li class="inner">...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

with...

```
#examples_list, #examples_list ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

To style it in a similar fashion.

Comment: It must be completely dynamic. Like in this screenshot: http://cl.ly/2C2o15451h3N1r3R3C2m

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on @b_benjamin response to a comment above, I think I might have one possible solution but I also think it will rely on some CSS that might not play well in older browsers, but it's a simple concept that can probably be adjusted with other tricks.

This seems to work in the latest FF, Chrome and IE9.

**First, the HTML:**

```
<div style="width:340px;">
    <!-- a list of text, with some time's marked up -->
    <ul class="sched">
        <li><b>17:55</b><b>18:10</b> <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a> sit posuere.</li>
        <li><b>18:20</b><b>18:30</b> <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a> sit amet orci aliquam.</li>
        <li><b>18:20</b><b>18:30</b> <a href="#">Class aptent</a> taciti sociosqu ad sed ad.</li>
        <li><b>19:05</b><b>19:17</b> <a href="#">Mauris et urna et</a> ante suscipit ultrices sed.</li>
        <li><b>19:05</b><b>19:17</b> <a href="#">Proin vulputate pharetra tempus.</a> Quisque euismod tortor eget sapien blandit ac vehicula metus metus.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Now some CSS:** (I used a simple color theme based on b_benjamin's sample photo)

```
/* reset default list styles */
.sched, .sched li{
    list-style:none; 
    font-size:14px; 
    padding:0;
    margin:0; 
}
.sched li{
    position:relative; 
    padding:0 10px;

    margin:10px 0; 
    background:#631015; 
    color:#FFF; 
}
.sched b{
    position:relative; 
    left:-10px; 
    display:inline-block;

    padding:2px 10px; 
    font-weight:none; 
    background:#FFF; 
    color:#666; 

}
/* some light styling for effect */
body{ 
    background:#cc222c; 
} 
.sched li a{ 
    color:#FF9; 
}
```

**Explanation:**

The [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) requires a certain thought process on how to achieve padding on inline elements (text).  One thing you can do is simply put padding around the entire containing box.

In my concept, I used a UL list and each LI element is the container.  I used a 10px padding on the container.

```
.sched li{
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

This will give us our padding, but it will cause our "time" elements to also have this padding.  My "trick" is to "fix" this by using a negative relative position equal to the padding:

```
.sched b{
    display:inline-block; /* make these items act like block level elements */
    position:relative; /* give the b elements a relative position*/
    left:-10px; /* offset them equal to the padding */
}
```

There's one last thing to do and that's to make sure the parent element is also position:relative so the child element will use it's containing dimensions:

```
.sched li{
    position:relative; /* needed for B elements to be offset properly */
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Here's a snip of what it looks like on Chrome.

[image]

You can, of course, play around with padding.  There's probably also some solutions to make the "B" elements float, but this seemed to work well.

I hope that helps!

Comment: One item to note.  There's no space between "B" elements that represent time.  This is necessary because of display:inline-block; will render white-space (spaces between elements).  I also skipped on making it too pretty, but one could easily add some background images to make the "arrow" effect in @b_benjamin example above.

Comment: Pss. In HTML 5 SPAN and B are equal in semantics (they have none).  I've seen (and adopted) the use of B elements for semantic less markup due to it's smaller size.  You can choose to use a more semantic mark-up as needed. =)

Answer (score 0):

Ben, 
   I don't understand why you would use two spans wrapped around the same element. Also, I rarely use spans because of their fickleness. From what I understand you want 3 blocks sitting side by side with the last element to be padded a little bit.

I would suggest simply adding an extra class to the padded div (or an id).

Try this...

[HTML]

```
<h2>double span with floated elements next to it</h2>
 <div class="box">box #1</div>
 <div class="box">box #2</div>
 <div class="box boxPadded">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus laoreet.
 </div>
 <div class="cleaner"></div>
```

[CSS]

```
.cleaner{clear: left; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
.box{margin-right: 5px; width: 100px; min-height: 25px; float: left;}
.boxPadded{padding: 3px 3px 9px 3px; word-wrap: break-word;}
```

So, now the third element has the attributes of the "box" class as well as it's own separate attribute "boxPadded".

The "min-height" is mainly for the third element. You can actually put it in the boxPadded class, but I'm a bit lazy. It will allow the element to stretch long if the text is larger than the element.

The "cleaner" is something I use after I float elements. Its' usually not needed unless you have elements in the floated element.

The "word-wrap" will allow a non space string that is longer than the element to wrap around the box.

Comment: Yeah, I hate <span>-s, too (I avoid them if I can). In your example the text does not have padding background. It breaks and the second line is transparent background. I dont understand why, because you se minimum height, not fixed... interesting.